# How to create rows in pandas based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
x        frames
0         7729.00  
0         7730.00     
0         7731.00
1         7735.00
1         7736.00
1         7737.00
1         7738.00
2         7741.00
2         7742.00
```

As you can see, the value for `frames` is sequential, but when `x` changes, there is a jump in `frames`. I want to continue `frames` so that it always increases by 1 and in this case, make `x` nan. Like this:

```
x        frames
0         7729.00  
0         7730.00     
0         7731.00
Nan       7732.00
Nan       7733.00
Nan       7734.00
1         7735.00
1         7736.00
1         7737.00
1         7738.00
Nan       7739.00
Nan       7740.00
2         7741.00
2         7742.00
```

#### EDIT

Here is the error I get using the first solution.

```
    df = df.set_index('frames').reindex(range(s.min(), s.max() + 1)).reset_index()
  File "/Users/asi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 227, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/asi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3856, in reindex
    return super().reindex(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/asi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4544, in reindex
    axes, level, limit, tolerance, method, fill_value, copy
  File "/Users/asi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3744, in _reindex_axes
    index, method, copy, level, fill_value, limit, tolerance
  File "/Users/asi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3766, in _reindex_index
    allow_dups=False,
  File "/Users/asi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4613, in _reindex_with_indexers
    copy=copy,
  File "/Users/asi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1251, in reindex_indexer
    self.axes[axis]._can_reindex(indexer)
  File "/Users/asi/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3099, in _can_reindex
    raise ValueError("cannot reindex from a duplicate axis")
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

If I have another column in the dataframe, like this:

```
x     y       frames
0     yes    7729.00  
0     yes    7730.00     
0     yes    7731.00
1     no     7735.00
1     no     7736.00
1     no     7737.00
1     no     7738.00
2     yes    7741.00
2     yes    7742.00
```

Then the solution turns all other columns (`x` and `y`) to NaN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with `range` by minimal and maximal values:

```
s = df['frames'].astype(int)
df = df.set_index('frames').reindex(range(s.min(), s.max() + 1)).reset_index()
print (df)
    frames    x
0     7729  0.0
1     7730  0.0
2     7731  0.0
3     7732  NaN
4     7733  NaN
5     7734  NaN
6     7735  1.0
7     7736  1.0
8     7737  1.0
9     7738  1.0
10    7739  NaN
11    7740  NaN
12    7741  2.0
13    7742  2.0
```

Or use right join in [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with helper DataFrame:

```
s = df['frames'].astype(int)
df = df.merge(pd.DataFrame({'frames': range(s.min(), s.max() + 1)}), how='right')
print (df)
      x  frames
0   0.0  7729.0
1   0.0  7730.0
2   0.0  7731.0
3   NaN  7732.0
4   NaN  7733.0
5   NaN  7734.0
6   1.0  7735.0
7   1.0  7736.0
8   1.0  7737.0
9   1.0  7738.0
10  NaN  7739.0
11  NaN  7740.0
12  2.0  7741.0
13  2.0  7742.0
```

Comment: I get an error using the first solution. See edit. Thanks!

Comment: @connor449 - So it means there are duplicates, for remove them use `df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['frames'])` before first or second solution (in second should working also if duplicates, but not sure if need this)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [complete](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.complete.html#janitor.complete) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html) to expose the explicitly missing values. In this case, we pass in a dictionary, pairing the column with a callable, that generates the rows from mininum to maximum:

```
#pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git
import janitor

new_values = {"frames": lambda df: np.arange(df.min(), df.max() + 1)}

df.complete([new_values])
 
    frames    x
0   7729.0  0.0
1   7730.0  0.0
2   7731.0  0.0
3   7732.0  NaN
4   7733.0  NaN
5   7734.0  NaN
6   7735.0  1.0
7   7736.0  1.0
8   7737.0  1.0
9   7738.0  1.0
10  7739.0  NaN
11  7740.0  NaN
12  7741.0  2.0
13  7742.0  2.0
```